# Solution Explorer vs Solution Navigator vs Class View

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been using Solution Explorer since I started with VS 2k3 and at this point my preference is as much inertia as anything else, so I'm wondering what features the other solution visualization options in Visual Studio had that might make them more useful.

I could just fiddle with the other two, but that method's much better at identifying what features they don't have that Solution Explorer does than at spotting what they do better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Solution Navigator is part of the Power Tools, not Visual Studio (directly).  It is basically a replacement for Solution Explorer and Class View both (which are part of VS, and have been for a long time), as well as giving you the ability to search quickly for things, pivot on a type or file, etc.

The searching feature is by far the one that I use the most in Solution Navigator.  Being able to search very quickly for types and files within your solution is very powerful once you get used to the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a faster way to open a file than with Solution Navigator.

1. Either copy and paste or type a file name into the search box
2. Double-click the resulting file